# Can I Make Use Of My CPU registers for my speed performance?

Tags: programming-languages, assembly, groovy, jvm

i know that accessing data from the Registers is very much faster than the memory access. Let us say in groovy, i have a code like this:

```
def anto = "Is this gets stored in register?"
println(anto)
```

If i need `anto` to be stored in the register for the performance consideration, how to do that? There is any way in programming languages to do this, mainly in Groovy?
I guess in C language we can do this by using `extern` keyword, how about in Groovy?

Comment: Since when does groovy compile to non-virtual machine code?

Comment: I guess a better question would be, how do you store a string in a register so that it makes any sort of difference (ie not just the pointer)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use such low-level features, use assembler.

Even in C, the "register" keyword is ignored by the compiler nowadays, since the compiler assigns variables to registers in most cases more efficient than a human can.

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  Groovy compiles to Java bytecode, which runs in the JVM.  And there's no way of assigning data specifically to a CPU register from the JVM.

Comment: so JVM takes care of this? Like it will have algorithms to make efficient use of the available registers in any particular time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fit a string (of any decent length) in any registers.